# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject

Tags: apex, trigger, filters

I want to replace a workflow field update with an APEX method to update the fields. The reason being is that I want to be able to add months to a date field and with formulas it only allows days to be added to the date.

I wrote this method to be included in the triggerhandler class for OpportunityLineItem.

```
    private void updateRenewalDates(Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> newMap, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldMap)
{
    // Create Lists to hold data
    List<OpportunityLineItem> renewals = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>> oppToLineItem = new Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>>();

    // Loop through filter records from the api call and see if they meet the criteria
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli:newMap)
    {
        if((oli.Start_Date__c == oldMap.oli.Start_Date__c) || (oli.End_Date__c == oldMap.oli.End_Date__c))
        {
            if(oppToLineItem.get(oli.OpportunityId)==null)
            {
    // If they do meet the criteria then add them to the list to update         
                List<OpportunityLineItem> oliLst = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
                oliLst.add(oli);
                oppToLineItem.put(oli.OpportunityId,oliLst);
            }
            else
            {
                oppToLineItem.get(oli.OpportunityId).add(oli);
            }
        }
    }
    // Get the record fields for records where the id is from our list
    renewals = [SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, Start_Date_Renewal__c, End_Date__c, End_Date_Renewal__c, Opportunity.ContractTerm__c 
                FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                WHERE Id in:oppToLineItem.keyset()];

    // Loop through results of the query and update the record with the new value       
    for(OpportunityTeamMember oppLineItem:renewals)
    {
        List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = oppToLineItem.get(oppLineItem.OpportunityId);
        for(OpportunityLineItem line:olis)
        {
    // Update Renewal dates with the start/end date + Contract length       
            line.Start_Date_Renewal__c = oli.Start_Date__c.addMonths(12);
            line.End_Date_Renewal__c = oli.End_Date__c.addMonths(12);
        }
    }

}
```

When i try to save the class and have it compile it gives the error:

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Map

On the line:

```
 if((oli.Start_Date__c == oldMap.oli.Start_Date__c) || (oli.End_Date__c == oldMap.oli.End_Date__c))
```

Where am I going wrong here and is there a simplier way to go about it?

Comment: Ah, you are learning the formatting ways. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oldMap` variable does not have a member named `oli`. Change `oldMap.oli` to `oldMap.get(oli.Id)` and you will then have your old record from the map.

To check if the value changed:

```
if (oli.Start_Date__c != oldMap.get(oli.Id).Start_Date__c)
```

You can apply the same logic to other fields, such as `End_Date__c`. You could also look at the [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) package, which lets you do:

```
Select.Field.haschanged(OpportunityLineItem.Start_Date__c).filter(newRecords, oldMap);
```

Comment: I changed the line to if((oli.Start_Date__c == oldMap.get(oli.Start_Date__c)) || (oli.End_Date__c == oldMap.get(oli.End_Date__c))) and get the error Incompatible key type Date for Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>

I know in your answer you said use oli.id which gives the record, but I want to compare to a specific field on the record.

Comment: That surely won't work. Your map key is `Id`, and unless your naming conventions are completely alien, the `Start_Date__c` and `End_Date__c` fields are of the `Date` type.

Comment: Right, I have two date fields and I want to see if they have been changed. So would you not compare the values in new map vs old map?

Comment: I get an error "Loop must iterate over a collection type: Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> on the for line. 

newMap is already set as  Map at the top of the method why would i get this error?

Comment: @Dan Your collection variable needs to be a `List<OpportunityLineItem>` if your loop variable is of  type `OpportunityLineItem`. In this case, `newMap.values()` instead of `newMap`.

Comment: That did it. I can save the class. Now onto seeing if it actually does what it's supposed to.